# Скачивание файла с помощью selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, загрузка

Всем привет, подскажите, пожалуйста, хороший метод по скачке файла с помощью selenium.
Если можно с простыми примерами.

html код для загрузки элемента, следующего вида
[image: код]

После скачивания, файл необходимо будет грузить в другую систему.

Comment: Ну, у вас есть ссылка, скачайте ее через [HttpClient](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient).

Comment: Вы тестируете сайт, или парсите? Если первое, покажите ваш тест и расскажите, какую задачу вы решаете, какой ожидаемый результат тест-кейза. Если второе, вы используете инструмент для тестирования не по назначению. 1) это сложно 2) это медленно работает 3) имеет ограничения, с которыми вы уже начали встречаться.

Comment: Тестирую веб-сайт, на данный момент решил проблему просто кликнув по элементу, в настройках указал директорию для сохранения, но теперь еще одна проблема, селениум не видит установленные сертификаты (работа с ЭДО)